# Yii's CActiveForm error message won't go away

Tags: php, yii

I'm writing a couple of (custom) validators for my form and everything's going smoothly as always but for one little issue.

I have two fields: one is a html select input (aka `dropDownList`) and the other is a simple `textField`.

I've setup my ajax validators so that, when option **X** is selected on my `dropDownList`, the text in the `textField` can't be empty.

SO when a user selects option **X** in the `dropDownList`, an error message (for the `dropDownList`, mind you) comes up: *text field Y can't be empty*.

Good so far. When I then click on the `textField`, type some stuff and click somewhere else on the screen, sure enough the ajax validator is fired off, and the HTTP response is empty meaning there are no errors on the form. **But the error message does not disappear!**

I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that I'm using one field's validator to `clearErrors()` on another field, but shouldn't this work? I've given the correct field as parameter to the `clearErrors()` method..

Has anyone any idea of what might be going wrong for me?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT** here's the link to my Form Model: [click](http://pastie.org/3701799)

when I change `target_constant` or `source_constant`, a validator is fired off to the server. It **is** working, and by that I mean that an AJAX response does get sent by the server to my validator being fired off. **In addition**, the response body has no error messages, but still the error message for `target_reg` or `source_reg` (depending upon which of those was affected) does *not* go away in the same instant. Only in the next request/response does the error message disappear.

Comment: Please post your custom validation function.

Comment: very very difficult to guess what is wrong without code, so put up your code.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a look at this, but couldn't find something wrong with your code. It seems that the actual validation works (you get the right data back), but the Javascript (yiiactiveform.js) only updates the data for the field last edited. This is contrary to a server-side validation, which checks all fields. From a user point of view, it makes sense to only display the error for the field you are currently editing, but when you have complex interactions, this is of course a little lacking. I was procrastinating heavily here, so I came up with a "solution". You can use the afterValidateAttribute callback on any attribute to force rendering error messages with $.fn.yiiactiveform.updateInput:

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'text'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'text'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'text', array('afterValidateAttribute' => 'js:function(form, attribute, data, hasError)
    { 
        mSettings = $.fn.yiiactiveform.getSettings(form);
        $.fn.yiiactiveform.updateInput(mSettings.attributes[0], data, form)
    }')); ?>
</div>
```

What does it do? in the callback, I get to work with some data. Most interesting here is data - this is the AJAX JSON response with errors for all attributes. In the function I then get the settings for the currentform. This is important, because I have to find the attribute object I want to manipulate. I then call updateInput manually, and pass the attribute object I want to modify, as well as the data and the form from the callback. Problem is here that you have to find out which zero-based index in the attributes object is your object. I did this by console.log. Et voila, your attribute gets updated.
I just hope there isn't an easier way to do this, and I spend this much time on it for nothing. :p

Answer (score 2):

do not add custom "ID" with `$form` html fields like this

```
$form->textField($model, 'test_field', array('id' => 'custom_id');
```

if it is necessary to add custom ID then you have to put model name before your Custom ID like this

```
$form->textField($model, 'test_field', array('id' => 'youModelName_custom_id');
```

another workaround for custom ID is to use custom class name.